# I'm trying to send email to user's through my web application. But email sending is blocked by gmail. Any solution please?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to sent email from my web application (an e-commerce site). i enabled "Less secure app access" from my mail account. And enabled `IMAP` also from mail setting. but still sending email is blocked or failed. What can be the possible reason for this? or i missing something in the code section?

here is code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
};
var sender = new MailAddress(senderEmail, senderName);
var receiver = new MailAddress(receiverEmail);
var message = new MailMessage(@sender, receiver);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC then I followed this [guidance](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en) to enable gmail smtp for my application.

1. Important is to have set `two factor authentication` for the account.
2. Create app password and use it in your application

then you use it as

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.From = new MailAddress(<your-gmail>);
mm.To.Add(address);
mm.Subject = subject;
mm.Body = body;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";                    
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<your-gmail>, <app-password>);

smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: thanks mybrave ... app password works like a charm.